# Problem with Eclipse Subclipse/Subversion Setup

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I am very new to configuring Eclipse to use a Subclipse client. I have set up our Subversion server and can connect to it via a command line. It appears to be operating successfully.

The problem I am having relates to installing a Subclipse client in our Eclipse installation.

When I navigate to the Help->Software Updates->Find and Install menu item I am able to select Search for new Features to install. At that point I create a new remote site which points to the CollabNet Desktop edition for Eclipse.

When the software is going through the next installation steps, I receive the following message: Mylyn Task List (Required) (2.0.0.v20070628-1000) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.ui (3.2.0)", or equivalent."

At this point I'm stuck, I don't know how to get the org.eclipse.ui and I can't continue with the install.

Can you help?

Cheers,

Kevin

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: Sounds like a version incompatibility problem with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse plugin system still is not helpful about determining dependencies.  Checking "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" might help.

Answer (score 0):

Subclipse does not require Mylyn.  The Subclipse update site contains a plugin that integrates Subclipse and Mylyn.  Since it sounds like you do not use Mylyn, just deselect that plugin.